# Setting button drawable through RemoteViews

Tags: android, button, icons, drawable, android-appwidget

I'm building a widget that has  a button in it. The icon in the button (which would normally be set through `drawableLeft="@drawable/some_image"` in XML) needs to change dynamically. I thought that I could use `RemoteViews.setString(R.id.widget_button, "drawableLeft", "@drawable/some_image")` to set the icon dynamically, but the widget just doesn't load properly. Does anyone know how to set the icon of a button in a `RemoteViews` dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawLeft` doesn't have a direct method equivalent: to set it from code you need to use [`setCompoundDrawables`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and its related methods. These are unfortunately multiple argument methods, which `RemoteViews` does not appear to make publicly available, so you might be out of luck there.

One possible solution (but very kludgey): implement multiple layouts with the different possible images and then use the [`RemoteViews.addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) function to load them up dynamically.

Might work.